# E-mail are sent only from two network connections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, sendgrid, nodemailer

I've got a problem with sending e-mails from my (let's say) contact form. It works brilliant when I'm connected to only two networks: my mobile hotspot and at my office. When I'm connected to any other network with internet access, it doesn't work (there are no errors, but no e-mails as well :( ... )

At first time I used SendGrid and I thought that the problem is within SendGrid. I even contacted with SendGrid support team and I was said, that code is correct and my settings are also allright. 
In the next step I tried a Nodemailer - unfortunatelly the same effect...

Need a clue, what might be a problem?

Below is my code responsible for creating and sending e-mail request:

Here's a code

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

require("dotenv").config();
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SG_MAIL_API_KEY;
sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});

app.get("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { recipient, sender, topic, html, senderName } = req.query;
  let subject = topic + senderName;
  const msg = {
    to: recipient,
    from: sender,
    subject: subject,
    html: html
  };

  sgMail.send(msg).then();
});

app.listen(4005, () => {
  console.log("Server 4005 is listening");
});
```

As I said before - it works perfect with two specific networks mentioned above.

EDIT:
Here is my fetch request:

```
fetch(
      `${window.location}/send-email?recipient=${email.recipient}&sender=${
        email.sender
      }&topic=${email.subject}&html=${myhtml}&senderName=${senderName}`,
      { mode: "no-cors" }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: [This should help I guess?](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#success-failure-errors)

Comment: You're swallowing the result and the errors here: `sgMail.send(msg).then();` You should always at least catch promises.

Comment: Both of you are of course right. No, at least , got an error ;)

Proxy error: Could not proxy request //send-email?recipient=mail2@gmail.com&sender=mail@gmail.com&topic=Owyeah&senderName=m from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

How about thay?  What should I do?